# Convert Timestamp format in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, time, timestamp

I want to change "2020-06-16T20:29:56.256+10:00" format to  "2020-06-16T20:29:56.256Z" this format. How can I do that in Elasticsearch query.
Please help,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [customized date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) as shown in the below index mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dinusha Kulathunga did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)